# Unknown column in 'having clause' in mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql, mariadb, having

i try to run a query with having:

```
        SELECT 
            `doctors`.*,
            (
                SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`areas`.`areaName` SEPARATOR ', ')
                FROM `areas_has_doctors`
                INNER JOIN `areas` ON `areas`.`areaId` = `areas_has_doctors`.`areaId`
                WHERE `areas_has_doctors`.`doctorId` = `doctors`.`doctorId`
            ) as `areas`,
            (
                SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`areas`.`areaId`)
                FROM `areas_has_doctors`
                INNER JOIN `areas` ON `areas`.`areaId` = `areas_has_doctors`.`areaId`
                WHERE `areas_has_doctors`.`doctorId` = `doctors`.`doctorId`
            ) as `areasIdies`
        FROM 
            `cats_has_doctors`
            INNER JOIN `doctors` ON `doctors`.`doctorId` = `cats_has_doctors`.`doctorId` 
        WHERE 
            `cats_has_doctors`.`catId` = '1' && `doctors`.`disable` = 0
        GROUP BY 
            `cats_has_doctors`.`relationId`
         HAVING FIND_IN_SET('1,2,3,4', `areasIdies`)
```

Server with `10.0.21-MariaDB - MariaDB` Server its working
but in server with:

```
5.5.61-cll - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

i got the error:

```
Unknown column 'areasIdies' in 'having clause'
```

what can i do ?

Comment: `HAVING` part applies earlier than `SELECT`. Put the original query in place of alias.

Comment: "HAVING part applies earlier than SELECT" @revo not sure what you mean i assume you mean `HAVING` can't use aliases from the same `SELECT` query? if that is what you mean you are wrong.

Comment: basically, `HAVING` doesn't get along with aliases... you'd need to specify a `HAVING + full subquery` or enclose everything except for the having into a one big query, then use having in the final output (which would probably mess with mySQL's optimization planning)

Comment: The `FIND_IN_SET` is backward:  The needle comes first, the haystack second.  Or you are trying the impossible:  checking multiple keys.

Comment: The manual states:  "This function does not work properly if the first argument contains a comma (,) character. "

Comment: It seems an bug in the interpretation of the backtick (\`) in the `HAVING` condition, only MySQL 5.5. See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mHXTpoUZAGukUVypSAjtLJ/1).

Comment: @wchiquito tnx its solved my problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it thinks areasIdies is a variable?

I would try pulling the areasIdies subquery into a temp table & trying that.
Just keep the query as it is to test, but just do that at the top and change the find in set param.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS areasIdiesTemp AS (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`areas`.`areaId`)
    FROM `areas_has_doctors`
    INNER JOIN `areas` 
    ON `areas`.`areaId` = `areas_has_doctors`.`areaId`
    WHERE `areas_has_doctors`.`doctorId` = `doctors`.`doctorId`
);

SELECT 
    `doctors`.*,
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`areas`.`areaName` SEPARATOR ', ')
        FROM `areas_has_doctors`
        INNER JOIN `areas` ON `areas`.`areaId` = `areas_has_doctors`.`areaId`
        WHERE `areas_has_doctors`.`doctorId` = `doctors`.`doctorId`
    ) as `areas`,
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`areas`.`areaId`)
        FROM `areas_has_doctors`
        INNER JOIN `areas` ON `areas`.`areaId` = `areas_has_doctors`.`areaId`
        WHERE `areas_has_doctors`.`doctorId` = `doctors`.`doctorId`
    ) as `areasIdies`
FROM 
    `cats_has_doctors`
    INNER JOIN `doctors` ON `doctors`.`doctorId` = `cats_has_doctors`.`doctorId` 
WHERE 
    `cats_has_doctors`.`catId` = '1' && `doctors`.`disable` = 0
GROUP BY 
    `cats_has_doctors`.`relationId`
HAVING FIND_IN_SET('1,2,3,4', `areasIdiesTemp`);
```

Comment: Of course, I would refactor this to then use the temp table, but I can't fully test without the data sets, so God speed.